# rf kill unblock all DOES NOT WORK!

Tags: rfkill

Ubuntu 12.04 Wireless Disabled by Hardware Switch, rf kill unblock all, and rf kill list DOES NOT WORK! What next?

All I get is "Command "rf" not found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### the correct syntax

The reason for the error *Command 'rf' not found* is because you have accidentally added a space character between `rf` and `kill`

The correct syntax is `rfkill command`

where `command` is one of:

```
    help
    event
    list [IDENTIFIER]
    block IDENTIFIER
    unblock IDENTIFIER
where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of:
     all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm
```

Since you appear to be trying to unblock a particular device the syntax would be:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

You should note - `rfkill unblock all` will only release the device lock that has been created by the operating system - i.e. a soft-block.

If your device has been locked by a physical device - for example, physical switch, keyboard lock such as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Function-key</kbd> then the `rfkill unblock all` will not work - this is a so called `hard-block`

You can see the status of devices with `rfkill list all` - example results are:

```
rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Thank you fossfreedom for your help, you gave a very informative answer. I will try this.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know fossfreedom, that I tried your advice, and it worked perfectly, you literally opened the door to 12.04 for me, and I am answering this using my 12.04 laptop now. Thanks again, really appreciate it.